# In godot, I want to run an animation tied to an animated sprite one time only

Tags: animation, godot

I can't do this at the moment because the system I'm using to detect input runs once every frame, meaning that the animation will continue looping every frame. I tried making it so that the animation would only run when the spacebar is being held down, but it just made it start and then pause when the spacebar is unheld, which  is not what I'm going for. Is there any way to make it such that when a certain key is pressed, an animated sprite runs its animation once and then stops? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Telling the animation that currently playing to play is fine. I believe the issue is with stopping it. For that I suggest having an "idle" animation. So that instead of stopping the current animation, you can tell it to play the "idle" animation (which could be as simple as one frame).

---

Now, if you don't want to tell the animation to play every frame, use [`Input.is_action_just_pressed`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-is-action-just-pressed) and [`Input.is_action_just_released`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-is-action-just-released), and that will tell you when to start and stop the animation.

---

And if you prefer to only run code if there is some input event, you can use [`_input`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-input). See also [_process vs. _physics_process vs. *_input](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/best_practices/godot_notifications.html#process-vs-physics-process-vs-input) and [Using InputEvent](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/inputs/inputevent.html#doc-inputevent).

---

**Addendum**: I paid little attention to "only one time". In the SpriteFrames editor, where you define the animations, there is a toggle in the bottom where you can tell Godot if you want the animation to loop or not.

In the odd case where you might want to change that from code, it would be something like this `$AnimatedSprite.frames.set_animation_loop("animation_name", false)` to make the animation not loop (you still need to tell Godot to play it, this changes how it plays from there on). Or you can replace `false` with `true` to make it loop again.